# Building Chromium for Windows

Tags: python, google-chrome, chromium

I am unable to fetch google chromium src. Chromium web site for instruction https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

I am trying to build it on windows 10, but unfortunately ended with below error Access is denied. [image]

Comment: Looks like `depot_tools` has not been setup properly. You should refer to this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

Answer (score 1):

Install git for windows and add got to PATH Variable